# MSBuild recursive copy

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, copy, visual-studio-2013

In Csproj I have the following section:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="C\MyPath\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <Link>Res\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    </Content>
```

Thus if C\MyPath\ has a following structure:

```
-C
 -MyPath
  -f1.txt
  -folder1
   -f3.txt
   -folder4
  -folder2
   -f4.txt
   -folder5
```

I don`t want exactly the recursive copy
but I want folder1 and folder2 not to be generated
but rather start recursive copy from the second level:

```
-Res
 - f1.txt
 - f3,txt
 - folder4
 - f4.txt
 - folder5
```

How can I do it without copying from each folder separately:

```
 <Content Include="C\MyPath\folder1\**">
              <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
              <Link>Res\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    </Content>
<Content Include="C\MyPath\folder2\**">
              <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
              <Link>Res\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    </Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [`MakeRelative` property function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx#BKMK_MakeRelative):

```
<Copy SourceFiles="@(Content)"
          DestinationFolder="Res\$([MSBuild]::MakeRelative(%(Content.RelativeDir), %(Content.Filename)))" />
```